# CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM with cudnnGetConvolutionForwardAlgorithm_v7

Tags: c++, cudnn, 3d-convolution

I tried to write an easy 3d convolution with cudnn but I encountered a vague error msg called after a successful compilation with NVCC: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM on the line of `cudnnGetConvolutionForwardAlgorithm_v7`. I checked the parameters inside this API and seemed Okay. Not know how to debug at this moment and any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

BTW, I am using CUDNN 8.4, CUDA 11.x and my operating system is Ubuntu 18.04. (Should not be version compatibility issue)

```
#include <cudnn.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

#define checkCUDNN(expression)                               \
  {                                                          \
    cudnnStatus_t status = (expression);                     \
    if (status != CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS) {                    \
      std::cerr << "Error on line " << __LINE__ << ": "      \
                << cudnnGetErrorString(status) << std::endl; \
      std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                               \
    }                                                        \
  }

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int H = atoi(argv[1]);
    int W = atoi(argv[2]);
    int C = atoi(argv[3]);

    int FH = atoi(argv[4]);
    int FW = atoi(argv[5]);
    int K = atoi(argv[6]);

    double* input = new double[K*H*W];
    double* kernel = new double[K*C*FH*FW];

    for(int k=0; k<K; k++){
        for(int c=0; c<C; c++){
            for(int i=0; i<FH; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<FW; j++){
                    kernel[k*FH*FW*C+c*FH*FW+i*FW+j] = (c+k) * (i+j);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int c=0; c<C; c++){
        for(int i=0; i<H; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<W; j++){
                input[c*H*W+i*W+j] = c * (i+j);
            }
        }
    }
    double* output = new double[K*H*W];

    cudnnHandle_t cudnn;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreate(&cudnn));

    cudnnTensorDescriptor_t input_descriptor;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&input_descriptor));
    int dimA[3] = {C, H, W};
    int strideA[3] = {1, 1, 1};
    checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(input_descriptor, CUDNN_DATA_DOUBLE, 3, dimA, strideA));
    
    cudnnFilterDescriptor_t kernel_descriptor;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateFilterDescriptor(&kernel_descriptor));
    checkCUDNN(cudnnSetFilter4dDescriptor(kernel_descriptor, CUDNN_DATA_DOUBLE, CUDNN_TENSOR_NCHW, K, C, FH, FW));

    cudnnTensorDescriptor_t output_descriptor;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateTensorDescriptor(&output_descriptor));
    int dimA2[3] = {K, W, H};
    int strideA2[3] = {1, 1, 1};
    checkCUDNN(cudnnSetTensorNdDescriptor(output_descriptor, CUDNN_DATA_DOUBLE, 3, dimA2, strideA2));
    
    cudnnConvolutionDescriptor_t convolution_descriptor;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnCreateConvolutionDescriptor(&convolution_descriptor));
    int padding[3] = {0, 1, 1};
    int strideA3[3] = {1, 1, 1};
    int dilation[3] = {1, 1, 1};
    checkCUDNN(cudnnSetConvolutionNdDescriptor(convolution_descriptor, 3, padding, strideA3, dilation, CUDNN_CROSS_CORRELATION, CUDNN_DATA_DOUBLE));

    cudnnConvolutionFwdAlgoPerf_t convolution_algorithm;
    int perf_count;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnGetConvolutionForwardAlgorithm_v7(cudnn, input_descriptor, kernel_descriptor, convolution_descriptor, output_descriptor, CUDNN_CONVOLUTION_FWD_ALGO_COUNT , &perf_count, &convolution_algorithm));

    size_t workspace_bytes = 0;
    checkCUDNN(cudnnGetConvolutionForwardWorkspaceSize(cudnn,
                                            input_descriptor,
                                            kernel_descriptor,
                                            convolution_descriptor,
                                            output_descriptor,
                                            convolution_algorithm.algo,
                                            &workspace_bytes));
    
    double* input_device;
    double* kernel_device;
    double* output_device;
    void* d_workspace{nullptr};
    cudaMalloc(&d_workspace, workspace_bytes);

    cudaMalloc((void **)& input_device, C*H*W*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void **)& kernel_device, K*C*FH*FW*sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void **)& output_device, K*H*W*sizeof(double));

    cudaMemcpy(input_device, input, C*H*W*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(kernel_device, kernel, K*C*FH*FW*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(output_device, output, K*H*W*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    const double alpha = 1, beta = 0;

    struct timespec time_start = {0, 0};
    struct timespec time_end = {0, 0};

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_start);

    cudnnConvolutionForward(cudnn,
                            &alpha,
                            input_descriptor,
                            input_device,
                            kernel_descriptor,
                            kernel_device,
                            convolution_descriptor,
                            convolution_algorithm.algo,
                            d_workspace,
                            workspace_bytes,
                            &beta,
                            output_descriptor,
                            output_device);
    

    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &time_end);

    double exec_time = (time_end.tv_nsec - time_start.tv_nsec) / 1000000000.0;

    cudaMemcpy(output, output_device, K*H*W*sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    double checksum = 0.0;
    for(int i=0; i<K*H*W; i++)
        checksum += output[i];
    
    cout<<"C3 checksum: "<<checksum<<"\t";
    cout<<"C3 execution time: "<<exec_time<<endl;
    
    cudaFree(input_device);
    cudaFree(output_device);
    cudaFree(kernel_device);
    cudaFree(d_workspace);

    cudnnDestroyTensorDescriptor(input_descriptor);
    cudnnDestroyTensorDescriptor(output_descriptor);
    cudnnDestroyFilterDescriptor(kernel_descriptor);
    cudnnDestroyConvolutionDescriptor(convolution_descriptor);

    cudnnDestroy(cudnn);
    
    free(input);
    free(output);
    free(kernel);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The kernel is 4-dimensional with shape of (K, C, FH, FW), and the input is (C, H, W), the output is (K, H, W) or (K, W, H). Let's say it is a square and no need to think about the order of H and W. I also tried reshape to have input to (1, C, H, W) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking at this, you can set the [cuDNN logging environment variables](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/developer-guide/index.html#api-logging) to printout info to why cuDNN API's failed.

```bash
$ export CUDNN_LOGINFO_DBG=1
$ export CUDNN_LOG_ERR=1
$ export CUDNN_LOGWARN_DBG=1
$ export CUDNN_LOGDEST_DBG=stdout
$ export CUDNN_LOGERR_DBG=1
```

Having the same issue, the logging reported that there were overlapping strides:

```
E! CuDNN (v8903) function cudnnFindConvolutionForwardAlgorithm() called:
e!     Info: Traceback contains 108 message(s)
e!         Error: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM; Reason: xDesc.hasOverlappingStrides()
```

Further reading, found that the strides should be [`an integer array defining the stride of each dimension (for example, the number of elements to add to reach the next element from the same dimension)`](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/developer-guide/index.html#tensor-descriptor).
e.g. `int strides[4] = {c*h*w, h*w, w, 1};` from github [here](https://github.com/mmmn143/cudnn_samples_v7/blob/master/mnistCUDNN/mnistCUDNN.cpp#L362C26-L362C45).